# Gate::before() is not getting called in Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

`Gate::before` is not getting called even though I have a `@can` annotation in my blade template.

I've written the `before` callback inside `AuthServiceProvider`. I've checked `gate::after` and it is working fine.

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
    * The policy mappings for the application.
    *
    * @var array
    */
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

    /**
    * Register any authentication / authorization services.
    */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Gate::before(function ($user, $ability) {
            die('before called');
        });
    }
}
```

Why might `Gate::before` not be called?

Comment: Laravel's documentation say `The before method of a policy class will not be called if the class doesn't contain a method with a name matching the name of the ability being checked.`

Comment: Have you registered any gates or policies?

Comment: Is the user logged in?

Answer (score 0):

Check your authorization policy for the middle ware.  Specifically:

```
'middleware' => ['web', 'admin.verify']
```

See more on Laravel's authorization middle ware: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization#via-middleware

From the link:

> Laravel includes a middleware that can authorize actions before the incoming request even reaches your routes or controllers.  By default, the `Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize` middleware is assigned the `can` key in your `App\Http\Kernel` class.

```
use App\Post;

Route::put('/post/{post}', function (Post $post) {
    // The current user may update the post...
})->middleware('can:update,post');
```

Try toggling those settings.